# Many-to-Many Relationships to Same Table with EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table where I need many to many relationships, an example can be a social network where friendships are kept. e.g.:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

corresponding to table

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
UserId int,
UserName varchar(255)
);
```

I need to have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE Friendships(
UserId1 int,
UserId2 int
);
```

where both fields are related to `Users.UserId`. How can I achieve this with annotations in EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would do it

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> FriendShips { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        FriendShips = new HashSet<User>();
    }
}


public class SocialContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(p => p.FriendShips)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(mc =>
        {

            mc.ToTable("userfriends");
        });
    }
}
```

A single list for each user will keep each users list of friends

Test:

```
    using (SocialContext ctx = new SocialContext())
    {
        User u = new User()
        {
            UserName = "John"
        };

        User uu = new User()
        {
            UserName = "Jack"
        };

        uu.FriendShips.Add(u);
        u.FriendShips.Add(uu);

        ctx.Users.Add(u);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: why is there one List<> Friendships and not two?

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
    public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> MyFriends { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> IFriendsForUsers { get; set; }

}
```

And in class EFDBContext : DbContext

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {                
           modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(t => t.Friends )
          .WithMany(t => t.IFriendsForUsers )
          .Map(c => { c.ToTable("UserFriends"); 
           c.MapLeftKey("UserId"); c.MapRightKey("UserFriendId"); });

          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```